# staticwebapp.config.json for Azure Service Apps

Tags: angular, azure, url-rewriting, virtual-directory

So I have an Azure Service App hosting a Service Side Blazor Application. I also have 2 Virtual Application in the Azure Service App for hosting 2 Static Applications (Angular).

```
Virtual Path         Physical Path             App type
/                    site\wwwroot              Blazor
/tourofheroes        site\tourofheroes         Angular
/gettingstarted      site\gettingstarted       Angular
```

When I launch one of the Angular Apps in the Virtual Application and navigate thru application (e.g. https://myblazorapp.azurewebsites.net/TourOfHeroes/detail/12) everything works as expected.

However, when I refresh I get an error message: "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." This is a well known issue with static apps like React & Angular.

I know using Github workflows I can include a file "staticwebapp.config.json" to include a NavigatioFallback & Rewrite rule which handles this issue. However, all 3 repo's reside on Azure Git.

The question: is there a way to apply Github Workflows and staticwebapp.config.json rules to an Azure Build & Release Pipeline?

Thank in advance for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can apply github workflow to the azure pipelines.

For that first you need to authenticate yourself using `personal access tokens` which are used to connect the azure devops to the github.

Once this is done you can create the workflow , commit/push the workflow and then click on actions tab in github  to select the azure pipeline.

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/github-actions?view=azure-devops) for detailed explanation.

Comment: thank you for your response. What if the company I work for doesn't want to use Github. They strictly want to use Azure Git as their git repository - is there a way to perform Github actions to release from from Azure Build Pipeline?